# Avoid single frame waiting state when passing already-completed future to a FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I have a list of `Future<PostData>` that I use to create a preload mechanism for tinder-like swipe feed consumption but I'm running into some issues. In fact, when a card is swiped, I rebuild the card stack using the next Posts that are already loaded in my `List<Future<PostData>>`.

Thing is, even tho my futures are already completed, I get a single frame of `ConnectionState.waiting` in my future builder making the UI jitter.

This limitation is documented in the docs:

> A side-effect of this is that providing a new but already-completed future to a `FutureBuilder` will result in a single frame in the `ConnectionState.waiting` state. This is because there is no way to synchronously determine that a Future has already completed.

I was wondering, is there a way to avoid that problem?

Cheers!

Comment: Isn't there something like a Completer Class in flutter, which completes Futures. Don't know if this helps you

Comment: @MarkusHein There is a completer class in Dart [doc](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-async/Completer-class.html) but I'm not sure how you want to use this in that case

Comment: You cannot do so with `Future`+`FutureBuilder`. Not in a clean way at least. Consider switching to `ValueListenable` instead

Comment: I'm sending the `List<Future<PostModel>>` from a BLoC through a stream. So that would mean converting it to a `List<ValueListenable<PostModel>>`, sending that through the stream and updating the values when they are ready from the BLoC ?

Comment: Could you post some code of your approach? In order to see what you could do in your case to avoid this problem

Comment: @ThéoChampion did you end up coming up with a solution to this using FutureBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can achieve that with `FutureBuilder`.
Consider creating a class that will handle network, caching etc.
Then listen to its changes with a `ValueListenableBuilder`.

Something like this:

```
class PostsRetriever{
  //handles loading, caching of posts
}

class PostsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final postsRetriever = Provider.of<PostsRetriever>(context);
    return ValueListenableBuilder<PostData>(
      valueListenable: postsRetriever.currentPost,
      builder: (context, currentPost, _) {
      //some ui that will draw currentPost'
      return RawMaterialButton(onPressed: postsRetriever.loadNext());
  };
}
```

You would need [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) library.